1-sided Hypothesis Testing
I am currently studying hypothesis testing and received a question with the following structure : Given a null hypothesis $\mu_x$=$\mu_y$, with samples giving $\bar{X}$>$\bar{Y}$, test the alternative hypothesis $\mu_x$<$\mu_y$.
I know that, according to $H_1$, we should conduct a left-tail test. But our test statistic will produce a positive t-value. How do I proceed with this question?
I understand that due to symmetry, we may use the positive t-value. Or do we fail to reject $H_0$ since our t-value is definitely less than our positive t-value of $\alpha$.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Edit: both X and Y are assumed to be Independent and Normally Distributed in small sample size with unknown variances.

The latter.
The problem statement is asymmetric so you cannot use symmetry: the conclusions could be very different left and right.
You can base the non-rejection of the null hypothesis purely on the small $t$ value, but the argument holds more generally if you do other tests than Student-$t.$ Generally, you would compute the $p$-value, i.e., the probability of obtaining this particular outcome or any smaller values of $\overline X - \overline Y,$ including the most likely $\overline X-\overline Y=0,$ purely due to random fluctuations. That probability will be more than $50$ percent, so definitely greater than any $1$ or $5$ percent significance level you may have adopted before carrying out the test.

Thank you for your reply. I forgot to specify the assumptions in the original question. Does the edit change your response at all?

It doesn't, apart from the fact that Student $t$ is really the correct test to apply (if the mean is unknown too).
